# Как правильнее передавать переменную между функциями внутри класса, если нет возможности использовать __init__?

Tags: python, классы, функции, pytest

На примере:

```py
class MyClass():

    def func1(self):
        x = 10 #нужно отдать эту переменную в func2

    def func2(self):
        print(x)
```

**UPD: Важное уточнение!** Этот класс существует в pytest как набор тестов, соответственно я не вызываю функции самостоятельно. Насколько я знаю pytest ругается на использование `return` в функциях

Comment: Не нужно было задавать отдельный вопрос. Скорее всего ответы не будут применимы к pytest.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass():

    def func1(self):
        x = 10            #нужно отдать эту переменную в func2
        return x

    def func2(self):
        print(self.func1())   #x


a = MyClass()
a.func2()
10
```

---

**Update**

```
class MyClass():
    x = 0          
    def func1(self):
        self.x = 10            # нужно отдать эту переменную в func2
        # return x

    def func2(self):
        print(self.x)          # x


a = MyClass()

a.func1()
a.func2()
10
```

Comment: Блин, я стер пояснение, когда правил. Этот класс существует в pytest как набор тестов, соответственно я не вызываю функции самостоятельно. Насколько я знаю pytest ругается на использование `return` в функциях.

Comment: @BrainDrill а так? Смотрите обновление.

Comment: Нет, так не пойдет, `func2` не видит переменной x, так как вызывается до 
`a = MyClass()`
`a.func2()`

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас простые классы и нет слотов и т.п.:

```
class MyClass:
    def get(self, a):
        self.x = a

    def printX(self):
        print self.x

q = MyClass()
q.get(100)
q.printX()
```

Comment: Нет так не работает, так как `printX` будет вызвана до
`q = MyClass()`
`q.get(100)`
`q.printX()`

Comment: метод `printX` вызывается после объявления `q`, вызвать его до объявления не представляется возможным

Comment: Да, просто эти функции будет вызывать pytest, а не мой код, соответственно pytest сначала выполнит содержимое `MyClass`. Это если я все правильно понял :)